# Web Service with SOAP Security crashes during transition to daylight savings

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, dst

I have a SOAP Endpoint on my web service that uses [SOAP Security](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd).

During the transition to daylight saving time this spring, my service went down with the error:

> com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: The creation time is older
>   than currenttime - timestamp-freshness-limit - max-clock-skew; nested
>   exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException :
>   com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: The creation time is older
>   than currenttime - timestamp-freshness-limit - max-clock-skew

The request that caused the crash had a soap header that was created at `2017-03-26T04:00:2.290Z`, and the error logged on the server has the timestamp: `2017-03-26 05:00:02,417` (exaclty one hour difference - likely dst related)

Is this a known issue with SOAP Security? Has anyone encountered this before and figured out a solution?

Comment: Which time zone/s is/are relevant here? In the EU, the transistion to summer time (DST) happened on Sunday, March 26, 2017 at 01:00 UTC, that is 1 day 4 hours before the creation time you mention. So I take it that you are located elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. The time zone is UTC 01:00 (Oslo, Norway). 

The request is a scheduled job that checks for changes in a database, sending a date as a parameter. The parameter in the request that caused the crash was '2017-03-26T00:00:01.000'

The query to the database is like this: "SELECT x from TABLE WHERE x.changeDate > ?1"

Comment: Hei i Norge, thanks for the edit and comment. It’s funny. If that parameter is to be interpreted in UTC, there ought not be any problem doing so, but as you said, you never know about software bugs. At least *I* don’t know. If it were to be interpreted in Europe/Oslo time, it would have been 1 hour before the summer time transition and hence couldn’t be related to it.

Comment: I supposed you have searched the net thoroughly for any description of any potentially related issue?

Comment: Yes, i have been activly searching/researching for a few days now. Thank your for your input, i will post back if i figure it out.

Comment: Hi @eirikaho did you find the solution of the problem, I am also facing the same issue.